# Velocity Warnings about "deprecated keys" that I don't even use

Tags: velocity

During webapp startup on Weblogic, I'm getting the following warnings in my console about variables that have been deprecated. I'm not using any of these 4 variables.

There were several other warnings from properties that I did have in my Configuration File (upgrading from 1.7 to 2.3), so I updated those and no longer get the warnings about them.

But these 4 are a mystery to me.

https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/configuration.html#configuration-summary-tree

> org.apache.velocity.util.DeprecationAwareExtProperties warnDeprecated
> WARNING: configuration key 'resource.loader' has been deprecated in
> favor of 'resource.loaders'
>
> org.apache.velocity.util.DeprecationAwareExtProperties warnDeprecated
> WARNING: configuration key 'webapp.resource.loader.class' has been
> deprecated in favor of 'resource.loader.webapp.class'
>
> org.apache.velocity.util.DeprecationAwareExtProperties warnDeprecated
> WARNING: configuration key 'string.resource.loader.class' has been
> deprecated in favor of 'resource.loader.string.class'
>
> org.apache.velocity.util.DeprecationAwareExtProperties warnDeprecated
> WARNING: configuration key 'runtime.introspector.uberspect' has been
> deprecated in favor of 'introspector.uberspect.class'

How do I get rid of these warnings considering I'm not even using these 4 properties?

Answer (score 1):

The warnings do show up because the file containing the default properties for Velocity Tools View, packaged within the `velocity-tools-view` jar, still uses the old syntax to be compatible with older engines.

It's possible to override `configure()` or `getProperties()` in a custom `VelocityView` class, but maybe not worth the effort. They can safely be ignored.

Comment: Man that stinks. You'd think that'd be something they'd want to fix so the default (and almost permanent) behavior isn't to throw up a bunch of warnings in the logs.